# Is two-stage logging in more secure?

Tags: authentication, web

I’m trying to find the correct forum for this question, so if not here, please suggest an alternative.

I notice a number of web sites now log in users in two steps: one for the username/email address, and the next for the password. In the past, both would be on the same form.

I’m not talking about two-factor authentication.

Is this just a fashion, or is there a security benefit to the two separate stages?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, it does. Thanks. I’ll delete this question later.

Comment: No need to delete if you don't want to :) It'll be closed as a duplicate and serve as a entry point for future searches :)